# Object as reference to recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass an object reference to a recursive function. I'm currently doing the following:

```
function Parent() {
    myBaseObject = {"data1": "123"}
    emptyObjectForReference = {}
    myFunctionToUseObjects(myBaseObject, emptyObjectForReference)
    console.log(emptyObjectForReference)
}

function Child(myBaseObject, emptyObjectForReference) {
    emptyObjectForReference = Object.assign(myBaseObject, {"Children": "myChild"})
}
```

The above is very simplified, but explains well what I want to achieve. While this example could use a return statement just as easily - The point of having a reference, is due to the fact that `Child()` is supposed to be a recursive function that does some work to my object as it calls itself.

Unfortunately, when I inspect `emptyObjectForReference` as the function is done - It still has it's initial value of `{}`. I would expect it to have the following output:

```
{
    "data1": "123",
    "Children": "myChild"
}
```

Does JavaScript, by default, not keep a reference to objects similar as to how it references e.g. a standard array? In case it is not possible - How would I then reference my object?

Comment: please add missing function and input, output and wanted output.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: There's only a syntax error in your example but no recursion anywhere.

Comment: @Andreas adding recursion in there, is not going to change the question -  I'm simply just stating why I want to pass it as a reference and not have the function return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to the local variable `emptyObjectForReference` has no effect on the caller's variable.

If you want to modify the object that was passed, use it as the first argument to `Object.assign()`.

```
function Child(myBaseObject, emptyObjectForReference) {
   Object.assign(emptyObjectForReference, myBaseObject, {"Children": "myChild"})
}
```